# Are there any designers for WPF resource dictionaries?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, designer, resourcedictionary, linear-gradients

I've discovered to my great annoyance, that once I move a color gradient or some other complex style to a resource dictionary it is out of <strike>Expression Blend's</strike> *Visual Studio WPF Designer Thingy's* jurisdiction and must be edited in XAML.  I have no issues with working in XAML except that it is more time intensive than a designer.  So my question is simple.  Are there any designers for resource dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Silverlight guy so possibly my answer is not valid. However in Blend you should be able to design resource dictionaries just fine. Go to the Resources tab and it should list all the dictionaries in your project. Expand the one you are interested in and you can design all the resources inside from there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ph33.png

If the resource dictionary in question is not listed in the tab, open its file (double click it in the Projects explorer), then it should show up. I believe this is a bug in Blend (I'm using 4.0.20525.0)

Comment: OK, I was wrong.  I'm not using Expression Blend.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I thought that Expression Blend was a tool within that environment.

Comment: Within Visual Studio there is no means to do this. Visual Studio's XAML editing capabilities are quite minimal. I recommend investing in Blend if you can. It's a pretty complex program with a bit of a learning curve but it can make working with Silverlight/WPF much simpler.

Comment: Being that is $599 and exempt from my MSDN subscription, its not going to happen.  Are there any other cheaper (freer) options? Some add-in for Visual Studio perhaps?

Comment: @Jordan I'm a bit late to the party but my answer should be the one you're looking for if you're not interested in Blend (although I agree that it's magnificent).

Comment: I've since started using Expression Blend for Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a way to do this in **Visual Studio**.

It's cumbersome but simple.
All you have to do is have the element that's using the ResourceDictionary in the designer, right click it, and in Edit Template choose Edit Current.

[image: Edit current template through Visual Studio]

It will open your ResourceDictionary, **along with your element in the designer**.

Comment: @Jordan Indeed, beats nothing tho ^^.